# How do I use Python 3.6 in Pycharm?

Tags: linux-mint, python3

I believe I've busted 3.6 | Potentially parts of my operating system too

Basically, I'm attempting to utilize the updated features of Python 3.6 in the program Pycharms.

Imagine my surprise to discover in Pycharms that not only is 3.6 absent from the selection within the Python Console settings tab, it's also horribly broken in my system:

https://pastebin.com/FJ91Wqh7
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

I configured 3.6 myself and it apparently broke other parts of my system as well. I'm no longer able to access my files or view folders in my menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yjeT.jpg

and.. Attempting to "configure" through right click on menu nets me an error that pops up in  top left:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9THL.jpg
        Execution of 'xlet-settings applet menu@cinnamon.org 0' falied: 
        Failed to execute child process "xlet-settings" (No such file or 
        directory)

What in the world have I done and is there any way to undo this and install/use/enjoy Python 3.6.4?

My operating system is Linux Mint 18.1... if more information is required please request it. I'm floored right now, so this is the best I've got.

Comment: Apparently, I'd even managed to uninstall the Cinnamon desktop too... For the love of god!! I just wanted to install Python 3.6!!! WHY!
https://pastebin.com/DtQP04Kt

Answer (score 1):

You have given a space between `python` and the version number. That caused `apt` to do some unintended changes to your system.

If you are able to boot your system and have a command line operational with internet access you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon python3.6
```

You may have to enter a console if your UI is not loading by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

Once you are in the command line do a ping test with:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

to check the internet connection. If your system didn't get the network interface up and connected, you  will have to do some additional steps.